# Why Opta planner employee rostering not assigning employees to shift even though they are available?

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

Currently, I have a roster of 30 shifts and 25 employees with there availability.
This 25 employees match the shift start and end time with employee availability.
Still, Opta only assigns 19 shifts and left all other shifts as blank and do not assign remaining 6 employees.

Here my assumption was, it should assign all 25 employees as their time matches with the shift.
Do I missed something here or should look at any other aspect as well?

Below is my Opta rules file, I have removed all other rules as they were not required in my case.

Opta employee-rostering version currently using 7.28.0-SNAPSHOT
time given roster for solving 240secs.

```
// ############################################################################
// Hard constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "Unavailable time slot for an employee"
    when
        EmployeeAvailability(
                $e : employee,
                $employeeName : employee.getName(),
                $startDateTime : startDateTime,
                $endDateTime : endDateTime)
        Shift(
                employee == $e,
                !DateTimeUtils.doTimeslotsMatch($startDateTime,$endDateTime, startDateTime, endDateTime, $employeeName))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100);
end

rule "No overlapping shifts for an employee"
    when
        $s : Shift( employee != null,
                    $e : employee,
                    $employeeName : employee.getName(),
                    $firstStartDateTime: startDateTime,
                    $firstEndDateTime : endDateTime)
        $s2: Shift( employee == $e,
                    this != $s,
                    DateTimeUtils.doTimeslotsMatch($firstStartDateTime,$firstEndDateTime, startDateTime, endDateTime, $employeeName))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100);
end

// ############################################################################
// Medium constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "Assign every possible shift"
    when
        Shift(employee == null)
    then
        scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100);
end

// ############################################################################
// Soft constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "available time slot for an employee"
    when
        $rosterParametrization : RosterParametrization(desiredTimeSlotWeight != 0)
        EmployeeAvailability(
                $e : employee,
                $employeeName : employee.getName(),
                $startDateTime : startDateTime,
                $endDateTime : endDateTime)
        Shift(
                employee == $e,
                DateTimeUtils.doTimeslotsMatch($startDateTime,$endDateTime, startDateTime, endDateTime, $employeeName))
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 100);
end

rule "Skill set preference"
    when
        Shift(employee != null, matchedPreferencedDisciplineCount > 0,$matchedPreferencedDisciplineCount : matchedPreferencedDisciplineCount)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, + $matchedPreferencedDisciplineCount);
end
```

> Here is my updated solver configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
  <!--<environmentMode>FAST_ASSERT</environmentMode>-->
  <solutionClass>org.optaweb.employeerostering.domain.roster.Roster</solutionClass>
  <entityClass>org.optaweb.employeerostering.domain.shift.Shift</entityClass>

  <scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDrl>org/optaweb/employeerostering/service/solver/employeeRosteringScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl>
  </scoreDirectorFactory>

  <termination>
    <secondsSpentLimit>240</secondsSpentLimit>
  </termination>

  <localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
      <pillarChangeMoveSelector>
        <subPillarType>SEQUENCE</subPillarType>
      </pillarChangeMoveSelector>
      <pillarSwapMoveSelector>
        <subPillarType>SEQUENCE</subPillarType>
      </pillarSwapMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>
    <acceptor>
      <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
      <acceptedCountLimit>800</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
  </localSearch>

</solver>
```

> Also it enforces me to implements Comparable on planning entity shift

```
public class Shift extends AbstractPersistable implements Comparable<Shift> {

    private static final Comparator<Shift> PILLAR_SEQUENCE_COMPARATOR = Comparator
            .comparing((Shift a) -> a.getStartDateTime())
            .thenComparing(a -> a.getEndDateTime());
```

> Will this resolve my problem of solver not assigning employees although they are available and will remove itself from local optima.

Comment: If you manually improve the solution by assigning one shift more, does the score get better? If it doesn't (it gets worse, for example the medium score improves but the hard score gets worse), then your change is not improving the solution actually.
If it does, it's stuck in a local optima - take a look at adding sequential subpillar change/swap move selectors.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet as per our comment I had verified after multiple debugs and came to the conclusion that part A of our comment is not a situation in my case rather it is local optima. I am still looking into adding sequential sub pillars but couldn't get how can I implement this in employee rostering example even though I had referred nurse rostering and flight scheduler. In nurse rostering, they are using shift window but in my case, I do need to select employee as per there availability. Will you please suggest how can I implement this in nurse rostering example.

Comment: IIRC the nurse rostering example has a custom sub pillar selector implementation, no need for that any more.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pilar based move selectors](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#pillarMoveSelectors) to escape local optima more efficiently.

Comment: hello, @GeoffreyDeSmet thanks for quick response above I have updated some changes after reading document but still, it doesn't solve my issue. please let me know what could be done to solve this .

Comment: Or if possible is there any example of how could I achieve this